# Block a list of IP addresses in ufw firewall

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, firewall, ufw

Is there a way to block outbound connections to a list of IP addresses in ufw firewall?

I need to be able to easily remove the blocked IPs from the ufw firewall at a later stage.